# Rails: TimeWithZone comparing times in different zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

Say I have a dispatch system running on eastern time, and it deals with events in multiple time zones. It has a method like:

```
def starts_today?
  event.start_time <= Time.current.end_of_day
end
```

How would you set this up so the `starts_today?` method is accurate to the event's local time zone?

Comment: Please click on check mark next to my answer if my answer helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to convert to local time which is easter time zone

```
def starts_today?
  event.start_time <= Time.current.end_of_day.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use local time also

*Time.now.getlocal.zone*

*Time.zone.name*

If u want all time zone use this one

*ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect{|z| z.name}.compact*

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html